# If I block my opponent's Ornery Goblin with my Ornery Goblin, whose Goblin dies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

Recently this situation happened to me on Magic: Arena. My opponent attacked with [Ornery Goblin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOrnery%20Goblin%5d), and I blocked with my own [Ornery Goblin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOrnery%20Goblin%5d). Surprisingly, my Goblin died while his did not.

I don't understand why. Here's what I think should happen:

- He's the active player.
- He attacks, I block. Both Goblin's triggers go on stack, but mine resolves first, since he's the active player (CR 101.4).
- My trigger kills his Goblin.
- Since his Goblin is dead, it can't deal damage anymore, so my Goblin survives.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both should die. This sounds like an Arena bug.

Once an ability goes on the stack, [removing the permanent that put it there doesn't stop it from resolving](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7893/5573). The ability is now an entirely separate object that has no reliance on its source.

This means both Ornery Goblins' abilities resolve, killing each other. Your assessment is otherwise entirely accurate including ability ordering—it just doesn't matter here that one kills the other first because they'll both die anyway.

The only other thing I can imagine is they had a Mentor put a +1/+1 counter on their Ornery Goblin or something, boosting it to a 3/2 which could survive the ping damage from your goblin.

Comment: Are you sure that both should die? Ornery Goblin's ability says "Ornery Goblin deals 1 damage to that creature", so if Ornery Goblin is dead, it shouldn't be able to do damage (?)

Comment: @Allure Yes. We use Last Known Information about the Ornery Goblin to know what the damage source is, but it's the ability dealing the damage.

Comment: @Allure [608.2g](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Resolving_spells_and_abilities), note _"If an ability states that an object does something, it’s the object as it exists—or **as it most recently existed** — that does it, not the ability."_

Comment: @doppelgreener well, actually it seems that according to 608.2g it _is_ the dead goblin.

Comment: @Allure look at Mogg Fanatic (Sacrifice Mogg Fanatic: It deals 1 damage to any target.) or Fanatical Firebrand ({T}, Sacrifice Fanatical Firebrand: It deals 1 damage to any target), both goblins with abilities that sacrifice themselves but say the now dead goblin does damage.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski it definitely is the dead goblin, won't matter most of the time, but if the goblin had deathtouch or lifelink, or if the creature blocking the goblin had protection from red or creatures it could matter.