# Walking Ballista and how it works

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I assume [Walking Ballista](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWalking%20Ballista%5d) does not need to survive for the damage on the stack to resolve. Also I assume that you can remove multiple 1/1 counters before letting any of them resolve

Answer (score 4):

What usually happens in the situations you describe is:

1. I have (say) a Walking Ballista with 3 counters on it.
2. I use Walking Ballista's ability to remove one counter and do one damage. While this ability is on the stack, my Ballista has two +1/+1 counters on it.
3. In response to the first activation, I activate a second time. Now there are two triggers on the stack and my Ballista only has one +1/+1 counter.
4. In response to the second activation, I can still activate a third time (or fourth, if there were a fourth +1/+1 counter on it).

And then when everything on the stack resolves, the target takes damage. If my Ballista now has a toughness of 0, it's dead, but since [removing the source of an ability does not stop the ability from resolving](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7893/does-an-ability-resolve-if-the-source-of-the-ability-leaves-the-battlefield), the target still takes damage.

Of course I could also sequence things differently. Instead of doing #3 above in response to the first activation, I could let the activation resolve, target takes 1 damage, and *then* activate Ballista again. Usually this won't matter, but if it does for whatever reason I can do this.

Comment: On a general basis, I'd advise you to let the damage resolve one by one before removing the next counter. There is no reason to prove to your opponent that you actually intend for your ballista to die until two of the damage has already happened. One exception is if you have reason to expect Split Second shenanigans. Also, I think it's worth mentioning at exactly what point the ballista dies: after the last ability has been put on stack, before anyone has a chance to respond.

Comment: In response to your three activations existing on the stack, your opponent casts Healing Grace, preventing up to 3 points of damage to one target.

Answer (score 0):

Abilities resolve independent of their source, so removing the final counter from a Walking Ballista will still deal the damage. This can be seen in [112.7a](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190612.txt):

> Once activated or triggered, an ability exists on the stack
>   independently of its source. Destruction or removal of the source
>   after that time won’t affect the ability.

When you activate an ability, it is implied that you pass priority (so your opponent can respond and the ability can resolve) unless you explicitly retain it. You can get this from [116.3](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190612.txt) and the [Judge Blog](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/mtr4-2/):

> Whenever a player adds an object to the stack, they are assumed to be
>   passing priority unless they explicitly announce that they intend to
>   retain it.

When you activate the same ability multiple times at the same time, in tournament magic, this is a shortcut for "I activate this ability, let it resolve, and repeat this process so many times". If you want to respond to each activation and put them all on the stack at the same time, you have to specify that you are retaining priority (otherwise the shortcut is assumed). This can be seen on the [Judge Blog](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/mtr4-2/):

> If a player adds a group of objects to the stack without explicitly
>   retaining priority, they are assumed to be adding them to the stack
>   individually and allowing each to resolve before adding the next. If
>   another player wishes to take an action at a point in the middle of
>   this sequence, the actions should be reversed to that point.

As an example, if you have a Walking Ballista with 5 counters on it, your opponent has a 4/4 in play and a Blossoming Defense in hand, and you want to kill the 4/4, it could play out as:

1. I deal 4 damage to your 4/4 with my Walking Ballista
2. In response, I cast Blossoming Defense on my 4/4

At this point, it would be assumed, because of the shortcut, that your opponent is responding to the first activation of your Walking Ballista (or a different activation if they specify otherwise), and you would still be able to remove the remaining 4 counters to kill the 4/4.

If you explicitly retained priority when activating the first 4 times, your opponent could counter all 4 of your activations with the Blossoming Defense (as they would all be placed on the stack before any of them resolve, and all would then attempt to resolve targeting a hexproof creature).

In general, it causes the fewest communication issues if you activate and resolve each ability one at a time, but if there are no communication issues, then it is quicker to use the shortcut above.

If you have a reason to do so, however, you are able to retain priority and put all the activations on the stack at the same time.